# AndroidGame - SurfaceView splitting? - BattleView

Tags: android, surfaceview, game-engine, xml-layout

I am trying to create a game with a battleview like in Pokemon or Final Fantasy. Right now I got a `SurfaceView`, which handles all the overworld stuff, like running around, changing the location, etc.

Should I create another `SurfaceView` and another thread for the battleView or should I keep everything in the same view?
Same question for in-game dialogues.

Comment: Do the surfaces need to overlap? Will you be updating them both at the same time, independently? The simplest thing for a full-screen game is to have a single SurfaceView that holds whatever you want to have on screen.

Comment: While in batttle, they do not need to overlap, i guess.
If a dialog or the in-game menu is active, the `MainSurfaceView` should just stand still.

Comment: (xref http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103854/overworldview-battleview-dialogues-how )